# What are the conjugacy classes of $SO(n)$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, rotations

I am trying to gain an intuitive understanding of what these classes represent (for $n > 2$). What do the elements of the same conjugacy class have in common? Can they be related by some notion of "amount of rotation"?

For example, if an element $g \in SO(n)$ rotates all vectors in $S^{n-1}$ by at most some angle $\theta$, then surely the elements in the conjugacy class must have some similar property, no?

Comment: All of the usual matrix invariants are also invariant under conjugation by special orthogonal matrices: Trace, determinant (not interesting in this case), characteristic polynomial, (complex) eigenvalues, multiplicities of eigenvalues, …

Comment: See also [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/221468/conjugacy-classes-of-so3-and-o3), for $n=3$, why traces are important.

Comment: In higher dimensions, you can rotate in multiple planes at the same time. In general, in $\lfloor\frac n2\rfloor$ planes. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotations_in_4-dimensional_Euclidean_space for the simplest example.

Comment: Are you familiar with the notion of an eigenvalue?