# Solve X in matrix equation of the form $X^{-1} B X = C$?

Tags: matrix-equations

Find X, and equation 
$$X^{-1} B X = C$$
where  A, B are known square matrices.

---

And how to find a "best-fit"(least square) X in  $$X^{-1} B_i X = C_i$$
Given know pairs of square matrices $\{(A_i,B_i)\},{i=1,2,3...}$

---

Another (maybe)relevant problem is to find X,Y in
$$X B_i Y = C_i$$
Given know pairs $\{(A_i,B_i)\}, i=1,2,3...$

---

Such problems has came to me several times.

Are there general methods to solve equations where one known matrix is being embedded in two unknown matrices?

Comment: Your matrix equation is equivalent to $BX = XC$, and here are some hints in the case of $3×3$ matrices: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/206623/solution-to-ax-xb-for-3-times3-rotation-matrices

Comment: wow, thanks, turns out the keyword is "Sylvester equation"